# Custom templated TextBox does not scroll to new character when text is too long

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am using the following TextBox style. If I keep typing in the TextBox, it won't scroll to caret if the text becomes too long.  And also I can't drag to scroll the text. Am I missing something?

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26"/>
    <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
    <Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Grid>
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                     Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Direction="-90" ShadowDepth="2"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" x:Name="GlowBd" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect Direction="360" BlurRadius="6" ShadowDepth="0"/>
                        </Border.Effect>
                    </Border>
                    <Grid Margin="2">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
                <!-- Some triggers -->
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Are you able to get to the end of the string in other ways (scroll bar, scroll wheel, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

This bit: `<Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>` says: let this text box scroll to the next line when you reach it.

This bit: `<Setter Property="MaxLines" Value="1"/>` says: I want it to have 1 line at most.

Removing the first, will cause new text push the old one to the left (You can reach it by hitting the Left key enough times).

Removing the second, will cause new text to push the old one up (you can reach it by hitting the Up key).

What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

The Content of the ScrollViewer in this case is the text, so if you want the text to cause scrolling, set the CanContentScroll property on the ScrollViewer...

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" CanContentScroll="True" />
```